# Multiple (9) tabs in a page, wise or not?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm using bootstrap in my web API page, and i'm planning to put 9 tabs in a page. Each tabs will have to load database values based on drop-down choice and the choice will be displayed in a table, then from the table they will make another choice and then that choice will be added with several other textbox inputs to be stored in the database.

So there will be a to-and-fro data retrieve and send process for each. Is it wise to do this? Does it affect performance? Or should i put those tabs in separate pages?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Haven't tried it yet because the code is too long for each tabs, so i was reluctant to make any changes yet..i'm afraid i will lose track of which code belonging to which tab..i thought if its worth doing then maybe i'll continue :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a UX/IA issue than a coding concern. I would envision using AJAX to load/refresh each tab's content, which could affect performance based on how much data is returned, how the data is displayed, etc.

I'm typically a proponent of the "less is more" mindset so 9 tabs may be a lot, but again this is up to your app's purpose and UX.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try out your suggestion :)